# fullcalendar scheduler resource onclick color change

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

Is it possible to set an indicator in fullcalendar scheduler timeline view? If a user presses on Resource title, I want its td to become background-color: blue. If a user clicks on another resource, its background becomes blue and the other (last) background becomes default again. Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() { // document ready

    var schedule = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        schedulerLicenseKey: 'GPL-My-Project-Is-Open-Source',
        editable: false,
        lang: 'lt',
        height: 500,
        header: {
            left: 'prev',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'next'
        },
        defaultView: 'timelineYear',
        slotLabelFormat: [
            'MMMM',
            'D'
        ],
        resourceAreaWidth: '15%',
        resourceLabelText: 'Vadovas',
        resources: [
            <?php
                foreach($items as $item) {
                    echo "{ id: '".$item->id."', title: '".$item->title."', eventColor: '".$item->color->name."' },";
                }
            ?>
        ],
        events: [
            <?php
                foreach($items as $item) {
                    foreach($item->reservations as $reservation) {
                        echo "{ id: '".$reservation->id."', resourceId: '".$item->id."', start: '".$reservation->project->start_date."', end: '".$reservation->project->end_date."', title: '".$reservation->quantity."',  url: '/manager/project/".$reservation->project->id."/show' },";
                    }
                }
            ?>
        ]
    });
});
</script>
```

I know I should use this function:

```
resourceRender: function(resourceObj, labelTds, bodyTds) {
    labelTds.css('background', 'blue');
}
```

I just do not know how to implement it to work the way I want.

Comment: @Cœur - Appreciate the zeal for proper spelling, but not really sure that this question was worth the time investment or the subsequent bump onto the homepage. It probably should have been downvoted (as unclear and not useful) and [roomba'ed](https://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba)

Comment: @JDB I roomba very low quality questions. Regarding this one, I'm not sure: so the vote will need to be from someone likely more qualified than me on the topic of PHP/jQuery.